# updating product quantity in Stock after ordering in order collection,MongoDB and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am working on an inventory system management using MongoDB,ExpressJs,ReactJs,Express, and my question is - how I can update a product quantity after completing it's order?

let me explain: if the product quantity in stock is 10 for example,then after ordering like 3 ,I want the product quantity to be 7 directly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const createOrder = asyncHandler(async(req, res) =>{
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id)
    if(!user || user.isAdmin === false){
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error('No Authorised')
    }
    const {
        customerName,
        customerAddress,
        customerNumber,
        orderItems,
        totalPrice
    } = req.body

    if(orderItems && orderItems.length === 0){
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error('No order Items')
    }
    else{
        const order = new Order({
            customerName,
            customerAddress,
            customerNumber,
            orderItems,
            totalPrice,
            user,
        })
        const createdOrder = await order.save()
        orderItems.forEach((item) => {
            Product.updateOne(
            {_id: _id},
            {$inc: {qteInStock: -orderItems.quantity}},
            (err, updatedData) => {})
        }
        res.status(200).json(createdOrder)
    }

})
```

I didn't find from where you are taking the `_id` to update the products collection.
And `orderItems` is an array so you won't get quantity inside of it.

You have to loop through each item of `orderItems` and update the collection.

Note :
send the response once after the complete process.
In the code, you sent before updating the quantity, I have changed the above code with whatever I could do.

Comment: Hey Sachin this one works,I just had to change the _id with item._id,...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to write separate your own logic for this however I can share the common logic which can be used.

Let's say you store the products in this way ( example ) : `{product : 'apple', quantity : 10, productId : 121 }`

then,

Once you receive new `order`, use the `product name` or `productId` ( I suggest using productId ), use

`products.findOneAndUpdate({ productId : productId }, $inc: {quantity : ( 0 - orderQuantity) }, (err, updatedData) => {})`

Here you might have to change the `products.findOneAndUpdate` to `products.updateOne` based on whether you are using mongoose or  MongoDB.

also `productId` is the productId you received from the request.
And `orderQuantity` is the quantity of the orders.

Comment: hello Sachin,thank you for your reply...but I have another question on where to put this code, in my controller or where I dispatch the create order in my frontend...thank you

Comment: You have to put your code in your backend where you are getting the request for **order**

Comment: I have put my backend order function try look at it,and tell me how to modify it